# How to compress 'odd/even number of times'?

Tags: word-request, numbers

If A occurs exactly *two* times, one could say "A occurs ***twice***."
If A occurs exactly *three* times, one could say "A occurs ***thrice***." etc.

Not being a native English speaker, I don't know how to properly name these words that compress the expression for "number of occurences", however, I've found articles online that have expanded their realm of existence beyond the numbers of 1, 2 and 3, such as "septence" for 7, etc.

I wonder if there are 'compression words' like this for "odd" and "even number of times". I would find these words extremely useful. There are words like that in Czech, I am however unable to find their English equivalents. Do they exist?

The Czech words for "odd" and "even" in the context of numbers are "***lichý***" and "***sudý***" respectively. The Czech language also contains a suffix representing the English standalone word "times", which is "***-krát***", used as in "**five" = "*pět***" -> "**five times" = "*pětkrát***", allowing for the words "*sudokrát*" and "*lichokrát*" (they are super scarcely used, but nonetheless legal). At another distantly related SE post, I've seen that there is a similar suffix in English,
"**-fold**". Is this true? If it is, can you therefore use "**oddfold**" and "**evenfold**" in the manner I require, that is

"A occurs ***evenfold***." or
"A occurs ***oddfold***."

It doesn't seem right, but that's why I'm asking here. If this doesn't work, does a correct word for this expression exist?

Comment: I don't think there are such words in the English language. At least in common use. Generally, I think, you would simply say: *A occurs an even/odd number of times*. Words beyond "twice", such as "trice", are not normal, everyday English, by the way. They sound old-fashioned and a little bit archaic. They are the kinds of words you would probably only encounter when reading English literature such the King James Bible, the works of Shakespeare or something similar.

Comment: @Michael The note about 'thrice' saddens me deeply, for I love the word. I hope people will see how powerful it is and start using it again.

Comment: @WeatherVane Very interesting! What does "alternately" say then? Either "odd" or "even" times? That would unfortunately mean all whole numbers, which wouldn't help my case. Could you please specify the context?

Comment: @Jan Are you absolutely sure you cannot use those words? It would make no sense if it was true, with the conclusion that one of us is incorrect. The only use would be in mathematical context, yes, that is precisely where I intend to use these words and how I've found (after a lot of searching) their Czech versions.

Comment: @Jan Words can be commonized. All words used to be uncommon. I'm not looking to create new words without backup, but I want to and will propagate these terms if they already exist. I'm just looking for some evidence, proof, a hint of them existing, something to which I can direct potential askers and say: "This word exists, here you go."

Comment: @Jan Well great! The more you know, right :D I will keep looking for English equivalents.

Comment: Cross-post of https://english.stackexchange.com/q/526128/64632.  Please do not post identical questions on more than one SE site.

Comment: @Chenmunka This is where I have been directed after my original question was closed for unjustified duplicity, looking for answers at a forum advertised as "containing less frustrated, less eager to close things off people".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Even times" and "odd times" are already in use in English, mainly in mathematics ([Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-third-grade-math/arithmetic-patterns-and-problem-solving/imp-patterns-in-arithmetic/v/examples-thinking-about-multiplying-even-and-odd-numbers)).

Also, [odd-fold](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=918&ei=00lVXseLL5XwxgOItaE4&q=%22odd%20fold%22%20mathematics&oq=%22odd%20fold%22%20mathematics&gs_l=psy-ab.3...95996.98408..99092...0.2..0.112.766.8j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i8i7i30j0i7i30j0i7i5i30.NXgzk6h1m44&ved=0ahUKEwiHwY6uju3nAhUVuHEKHYhaCAcQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) and [even-fold](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1280&bih=918&ei=N0pVXuqQMrGr1fAP9buc4A0&q=%22even%20fold%22%20mathematics&oq=%22even%20fold%22%20mathematics&gs_l=psy-ab.3...48268.49674..50018...2.0..0.88.700.9......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i8i7i30j0j0i8i30.WTQ95EYcT-A&ved=0ahUKEwiqiOndju3nAhWxVRUIHfUdB9wQ4dUDCAs&uact=5) are used. Or with one word: oddfold and evenfold.

You need to care about this:

- "Even fold" as two separate words can mean folding something evenly.
- "Odd times" can mean "strange times."